# What to do about the third derivative of a twice differentiable function?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, economics, research

In my economics dissertation, I have a general production function: $F:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that maps input onto unit output. $F$ is unspecified (besides that $F'>0$ and $F''>c$, for some $c<0$). The assumption (widespread in the literature) is that $F$ is twice differentiable. However, when performing analysis, I derive equations that involve the third derivative of $F$. Including $F'''$ without assigning it a particular value would probably result in indeterminate results. I could assume $F'''=0$ but this strikes me as somewhat contrived. Are there any other options?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. If you specify $F$, then $F'''$ is also specified. You don't get to specify $F$ and then make $F'''$ whatever you want. What is the representation of $F$? Formula, graphical, tabular, or verbal?

Comment: $F'''$ is unspecified. It's some general strictly increasing function.

Comment: Do you have any control over $F$? If so, what do you get to proscribe?

Comment: What is your definition of $F''$ for $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, when $n>1$?

Comment: @uniquesolution, that would be a production function from multiple inputs onto 1 output.

Comment: It's still really unclear exactly what you're trying to do. I will say this: $F$ being maximally twice differentiable and $F'''=0$ are incompatible. If you state that $F'''=0$, then it is thrice differentiable there.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Ah yes. That's right. So $F'''$ is undefined?

Comment: Why don't you just assume that $F$ is three times differentiable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to check:

- Can you get by with a weaker condition, e.g., Lipschitz or Hölder continuity of $F^{(\text{ii})}$?
- Do you need $F^{(\text{iii})}$, or just integrals of functions multiplied by $F^{(\text{iii})}$? If the latter holds, you only need weak derivatives.
- Much of microeconomic theory can be expressed in the context of convex optimization—functions don't need to be assumed differentiable for monotonicity and strong convexity to make sense. Are you *absolutely sure* that you need the third derivative of a function?
- One differentiability requirement that has become common in the convex optimization literature is [*self-concordance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-concordant_function): $$F^{(\text{iii})}(t)^2\leq 4F^{(\text{ii})}(t)^3\text{.}$$ Maybe this property is what you actually need?